# How to make real lazyloading with nativescript angular tabs and BottomNavigation

Tags: angular, tabs, nativescript, lazy-loading, bottomnavigationview

I am implementing app with nativescipt. I have added BottomNavigation (by following some examples on internet) with lazyLoading and going to to same with Tab component in child pages. Code looks like this

```
export const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/(searchTab:search//contactsTab:contacts//accountTab:account)',
    pathMatch: 'full'
},

{
    path: 'search',
    component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
    loadChildren: () => import('@src/app/components/search/search.module').then((m) => m.SearchModule),
    outlet: 'searchTab',
},
{
    path: 'contacts',
    component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
    loadChildren: () => import('@src/app/components/contacts/contacts.module.tns').then((m) => m.InquiriesModule),
    outlet: 'inquiriesTab',
},
{
    path: 'account',
    component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
    loadChildren: () => import('@src/app/components/account/account.module').then((m) => m.AccountModule),
    outlet: 'accountTab',
}
```

];

and standard HTML (will not copy here because it can be found in NS documentation)

However, according to NS documentation, -

> Preloading: At least 1 to the sides (because of the swipe gesture)
>   https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-components/tabs

I have expected that only side tabs will be preloadd but account tab is the third... I would accept that behaviour  because lazyLoading at least would be usefull for some tabs but i have added console.log() to all 3 tab components and all of them were triggered.
I hava read that this behaviour can be controlled in TabView by canging 'androidOffscreenTabLimit' property

so questions follows:
1) How can i control preloading behaviour for BottomNavigation and Tab
2) Can i disable preloading at all?
3) And what word 'at least 1 to the side' means?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let say if `offscreenTabLimit` is set to 1, and your current tab index is also 1 then, all tabs from index 0 through 2 will be loaded at once (Previous Tab + Current Tab + Next Tab). And no you can not avoid this on Tabs component, but if you use BottomNavigation you can.

Comment: My current tab index is 0 but tabs with index 1 and 2 are loaded. :( How can i avoid it with BottomNavigation?

Comment: By default bottom navigation loads only current index. If you find issues with either of the components, please share a Playground sample where it can be reproduced.

Comment: I have created playground for it: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=J5oNhi&v=4

i will report issue too

Comment: Hmm, the actual views are created only when you load the tab. Though the Angular component is created upfront, may be because you have to set router path for all 3 tabs at once (`/(searchTab:search//accountTab:account//thirdTab:third)`). You could load router with only path for first tab, then update route path whenever other tabs are loaded - based on selected index, but that's a bit overhead. If you just want to know when the tab is actually rendered in order to load data / hit APIs, use loaded event on your root view instead of ngOnInit.

Comment: Can you share link with ore info about how to use loaded event with angular? But it looks a bt strange that lazyloading loads components before they are rendered. this was marked as a bug: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/2147 more than that - if we cannot trust ngOnInit how can we trust ngOnDestroy

Answer (score 1):

With Tabs component at least the current tab and next / previous tabs are preloaded. You may avoid preloading if you BottomNavigation instead.

Also when you use Angular & lazy loading, the path for each outlet is generally set at once which will load all modules at once. To avoid this you may set the path only for primary outlet initially, then set path for other outlets as user change tabs. But this could a overhead, if the purpose behind is to know when the tab is actually getting rendered then you may simply use `loaded` event.

**HTML**

```
         <TabContentItem>
            <GridLayout rows="0, *, auto, auto" (loaded)="onLoaded(1)">
                <page-router-outlet name="searchTab" row="1" rowSpan="2"
                    actionBarVisibility="never">
                </page-router-outlet>
                <Label row="2" class="shadow"></Label>
                <Label row="3" class="bottom-border"></Label>
            </GridLayout>
        </TabContentItem>
        <TabContentItem>
            <GridLayout rows="0, *, auto, auto" (loaded)="onLoaded(2)">
                <page-router-outlet name="accountTab" row="1" rowSpan="2"
                    actionBarVisibility="never">
                </page-router-outlet>
                <Label row="2" class="shadow">
                </Label>
                <Label row="3" class="bottom-border"></Label>
            </GridLayout>
        </TabContentItem>
        <TabContentItem>
            <GridLayout rows="0, *, auto, auto" (loaded)="onLoaded(3)">
                <page-router-outlet name="thirdTab" row="1" rowSpan="2"
                    actionBarVisibility="never">
                </page-router-outlet>
                <Label row="2" class="shadow"></Label>
                <Label row="3" class="bottom-border"></Label>
            </GridLayout>
        </TabContentItem>
```

**TS**

```
onLoaded(index) {
    console.log(`Tab ${index} loaded`);
}
```

**Note:** loaded event could be triggered every time when you visit the tab, if you are planning to make API calls here then you might want to add conditions to ensure if you have already loaded data.

Comment: Hi, thanks for v an answer. Can you drop example code how it can look to set path path for other tabs on tab b change? Because purpose of this is to have real lazy loading. I would really appreciate and would mark an answer as answered.

Comment: I have implemented your advice in playground it seems that it works:play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=J5oNhi&v=7 However second time that i navigate to tab ngOnInit is not triggered - but i have data read from server there. Should i move it somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this with **ngOnChanges()** lifecyclehook in the component which should be loaded on tab icon click. (for my case its notification component)

**Tab component View**

```
<TabContentItem>
            <StackLayout>
                <user-notification
                [tabindexes]="selectedTabIndex"
                (readNotificationEvent)="doneReadNotifications($event)"></user-notification>
            </StackLayout>
</TabContentItem>
```

SelectedTabIndex will get updated on tab changes.
**Tab component TS**

```
selectedIndexChanged(event) {
        this.selectedTabIndex = event.newIndex;
        console.log("Index Changed : " + JSON.stringify(event.newIndex));
        console.log("Selected Index " + this.selectedTabIndex);
}
```

**Notification component TS file.**

```
ngOnChanges(){
        console.log("\nNotificationsOn Changes is called" + this.tabindexes);
// here you can write your code which needs to be called only when this tab is switched.
    }
```

This is just a workaround, hope it's clear. really sorry bad documentation though...